dynamic initialisation of global statics, races and timing
Is it guarantied that global statics are (dynamically) initialised before e.g. main() is called resp. LoadLibrary()/dlopen() returns? Or is it possible that they get "lazy" initialised - just before any function in the specific translation unit is called?
Second question, is the initialisation always serial, even over multiple translation units, or races could occur?

Global states are source of evil in software. Anyway your question is so broad and so general that it is hard to provide short answer. Please focus your question. Meanwhile this can be useful: https://youtu.be/dOfucXtyEsU

Globals (global state) ruin a lot of things (specially unit testability and maintainability) and can lead to things like the static initialization fiasco. Avoid them if you can and learn about dependency injection (either through abstract baseclasses or template programming techniques). So if you can spent energy on learning how to design software without them instead of trying to understand all the risks involved in using them.

Really really watch this too (refers to "spooky action at a distance" when using globals). Value Semantics: Safety, Independence, Projection, & Future of Programming - Dave Abrahams CppCon 22. I guess that after watching this you never want global variables again.

About lazy initialization : It is kind of possible with Meyer's singletons... but you will have global state again. (singletons are globals too)

Deferred_dynamic_initialization

@Pepijn I thought about (mis)use the ctor/dtor of a global static variable to create a kind of init/deinit function for my library. Normally I try to avoid globals, especially across translation units.

@albert Oh good happy to hear you already try to avoid globals ;) And I understand your conundrum now a lot better too. I think this is why a lot of API's end up with an initialize/unitialize call.

From Deferred_dynamic_initialization

It is implementation-defined whether dynamic initialization happens-before the first statement of the main function (for statics) or the initial function of the thread (for thread-locals), or deferred to happen after.

So it is not guarantied that global statics are (dynamically) initialised before main() generally. You have to see with your compiler documentation for more guaranty.

Why is it so damn difficult to build a function that is called after the CRT initialization (including dynamic init of statics), but before start of main() or return of dlopen()?

Put the global in main, you are guarantee their initialization happens (in order :-) ) and in a single TU that you dlopen and have a Init function to call
